# matching dates without using a loop

Tags: matlab

I have a date vector date_vec which say has every day from 2000 until today (stored as a date number). I then have a matrix called sale_matrix which is of type double and size 8000 x 4.

What I need to do is find the index number for each date in my sales matrix. I was looking at datefind however that always returns the results in an order list and these dates will not be in any order. Looking at MATLAB date functions I cannot see anyway other than using a for loop. Is there another way to solve this problem?

**Edit**

Example of sales matrix below. Please note the dates are actually stored as numbers in the matrix I am using dates below as it's bit easy to read.

Also NaN's can be replaced by a dummy date if it makes things easier.

```
 sales matrix 
 potential_sale   confirmed_sale     completed_sale    cancelled_sale
 2000-05-06       2000-06-02         2000-08-15        NaN
 2004-11-14       2005-01-05         NaN               2005-01-12
 2002-02-16       2002-02-25         2002-04-10        NaN
 2010-03-08       2010-04-01         2010-04-19        NaN
```

Comment: Some sample values of `sale_matrix` might help us understand it in a better way.

Comment: So, you have `sales_matrix` as a matrix of `datevectors` with some of them as `NaNs`, right?

Comment: Then, how about this - `sales_matrix - datenum('2000-01-01') + 1`? That `+1` is to start the indexing from `1` instead of `0`, because of the subtraction. Not entirely sure if you were looking for this though.

Comment: ah yeh! nice and simple. Think I was over thinking it, thanks again!